# C# - updating label while adding items to ListView

Tags: c#

I have a ListView which I populate with a lot of items, over 3000. This can take up to 15 seconds.
Every time I add an item I want to update a label stating how many items have been added so far.
To do so I use this code:

```
foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    DateTime dt = GetDateTakenFromImage(Path.Combine(f.Directory.ToString(), f.Name));
    count++;
    labelLoadedLeft.Text = "Loading " + count + " files so far";
    ListViewItem lSingleItem = lv.Items.Add(f.Name);

    lSingleItem.SubItems.Add(dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
    lSingleItem.Tag = Path.Combine(f.Directory.ToString(), f.Name);
}
```

Unfortunately the label does not show until all items have been loaded.

I understand this has to do with the fact that I am doing a lengthy operation on thr UI thread and that I should probably be using a backgroundworker to do the work.

Does anyone know of good and simple examples on how to use background worker. What I have found so far is too complicated for me or too convoluted.

Thank you

Crouz

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: Aside of threading, you could make your inserting operation more efficient either by calling `BeginUpdate\EndUpdate` methods on a list view, or just inserting all items at once using `AddRange`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look these up as soon as I get back home

Answer (score 1):

If you only want your Label to update, you should update it.

```
labelLoadedLeft.Text = "Loading " + count + " files so far";
labelLoadedLeft.Update();
```

Which version of VS/C# do you use? With VS2012/C#5.0 you could take advantage of the new "await" feature. It makes code easy to read and updating the UI can be done without invoke etc

Comment: Hi,thank you for the answer, this is working fine, although the entire operation seems a little slower, maybe me though. I use VS2010

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a BackgroundWorker, here's an example, http://dotnetforum.net/topic/34729-how-to-cancel-backgroundworker-during-getfiles/.

However, the UI will never show anything until the you get a list of all files.  And as you said this is slow.

Use the `EnumerateFiles` method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.100).aspx, which returns one file at a time.

Comment: As @YYY mentioned, TPL is better than a `BackgroundWorker`.  But you still must use EnumerateFiles to get a zipping UI.

Answer (score 1):

A background worker is most easily handled via the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), presuming you're working with .NET 4.0.  You can start a worker in the background using code that looks like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
   // Background Worker Stuff goes here
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

You can then put your worker's job in another class/function, and have it `yield return` its results from `DoWork()`, giving you an `IEnumerable<T>` of whatever it's returning.  Using your `foreach` loop over that like so:

```
foreach(var item in DoWork())
{
   // Update UI
}
```

Will mean you can update the UI as results come back.  `Yield return` will allow you to handle items before the entire enumerable returns.  Be careful, though - `yield return` implicitly sets up a state machine inside your program, so unless you need functionality like this it can be very wasteful to use this idiom.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need it. Use Begin/EndUpdate on the ListView.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx

This will prevent drawing of the items until they're all loaded. You won't be able to maintain a count, but I don't really see the benefit of that at all, especially if this makes it too fast to matter.